# MongoDB aggregation group

Tags: mongodb

I need few values to pass through the pipeline(without changes) to the subsequent pipeline aggregator while using a group

For eg if my input is

> { "_id" : 1, "tags" : [ "a", "b", "b", "c" ], "text" : "a" },
>   { "_id" : 2, "tags" : [ "a", "c" ], "text" : "b" }

and I like the output to be

> { _id: 1, tags : [a,b,c], text : a} , { _id: 2, tags : [a,c], text : b}

I did an unwind and group and do $addToSet to remove the dups. My question is how do I make

`text` appear in the output as is. the text key and values need to just pass through this pipeline, However i am forced to use accumulators

I tried this code so far

> use test
>
> var unwind = { $unwind : "$tags"};
>
> var group = { $group : { _id : "$_id" , tags : { $addToSet : "$tags" }
>   , text : { $first : "$text" }}};
>
> db.test.aggregate(unwind,group)

and it works fine but that is not the intention of $first and it is suggested to be used with sort. What is the right way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using `$first` for this.  As an alternative, you could add `text` to your `_id`, but that's hardly better as then you'd need to add a `$project` to the end of your pipeline to move it back out of `_id`.

You have to do the same sort of mildly awkward thing with SQL group bys.

Comment: Agreed, `$first` is a good option here. Grouping by two fields (`_id` and `text` in this case) in general can produce very different `$group` results than using just one field, since there could be more unique combinations of the two fields. Since Muhilan is grouping by `_id` here, though, it won't make a difference in this case.

Comment: I had different results with grouping with _id and text(similar fields in a bigger dataset) and also i felt it would be performance hit to unnecessarily group just for passing the value.

Answer (score 0):

All fields but the `_id` field must use an accumulator with `$group`, as specified in the [`$group` documentation page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group). The problem is that it's unclear what it would mean to "pass" a value through the pipeline with `$group`, since MongoDB has no way of knowing that the value of that field is going to be the same for all documents you are grouping together. You have to choose what value you want for that field with the accumulator.